# How to create an array of objects in data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to have an array of objects and save it to JSON in Data Factory.

```
[
 {"abc":123},
 {"bca":123}
]
```

I can save it to JSON but it omits the comma (,).

This is my flow
[image]

My aggregate function

```
collect(@(abc=abc, ...))
```

This gives my an array for each object which is not what I want. I would like to wrap all the lines in one array.

**Update**
The image below shows the flattening of the incomming stream.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an expected output?

Comment: [
 {"abc":123},
 {"bca":123}
]

Comment: Can you share your source structure?

Comment: The flatten activity returns a simple structure with values of type integers and strings. So how to seperate each element with a  comma, and put all the objects in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the structure first in a Derived Column, then collect() that structure in an Aggregate.

[image]

[image]